# Solving the Elliptic Integral of the First Kind with Imaginary Moduli

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

The Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind is defined as the following:

$$K(m)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2(x)}}$$

Given this definition, I would like to solve the following question:

$$
K(i)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-i\sin^2(x)}}
$$

How should I start? I assume I’m missing some crucial identity that would allow me to find the answer immediately.

Furthermore, I would like to know if there is an identity for all imaginary moduli, such as
$$K(m) = K(n\cdot i)$$

where $n$ is a real number.

Comment: How is this even defined?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the square root of a nonpositive number? Do you refer to the existence of roots for holomorphic functions?

Comment: I suppose, but I assume that it’s not that important considering that we’re talking about the anti derivative of this function.